# How to add arguments to profile chrome or global chrome (with profiles) shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, windows-11, shortcuts

I am trying to disable Windows 10 custom title bar on Google Chrome.
I am failing to do this because my Google Chrome is with profiles.
How can I disable the custom title bar on different profiles on chrome?
I have different profiles on my Google Chrome. I can't turn off the custom title bar by adding the argument (--disable-windows10-custom-titlebar) to Google Chrome.
Likewise, I want to disable Windows 10 custom title bar on all profiles.
Specific steps I did:

1. Have two or more profiles on Google Chrome
2. add the argument --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar to any shortcut
3. try to run the shortcut or apply the settings to the shortcut.
4. a new profile is opened with Windows 10 custom title bar turned on when opening the profile shortcut or an error when adding an argument to the global chrome shortcut, as shown in the images below.

To disable Windows 10 custom title bar on chrome by having an option or something, or force chrome to disable Windows 10 custom title bar with another workaround.

**The alternatives I've considered:**
I tried the argument on different shortcuts. In addition, I tried another argument (--disable-features=Windows10CustomTitlebar) on the shortcuts. But none worked.

Adding the argument --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar to specific profile chrome shortcut
[image: adding the argument --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar to specific profile chrome shortcut]

adding the argument --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar to global chrome shortcut
[image: adding the argument --disable-windows10-custom-titlebar to global chrome shortcut]

Comment: Why this question has [tag:windows-10] and [tag:windows-11]?

Comment: It looks that it will be better to replace [tag:shortcuts]  by [tag:file-shortcuts] as the last is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Ok It is about ordering of the arguments, You need to disable native accent color and than open the desired profile.

So it's something like adding the argument

```
--disable-windows10-custom-titlebar
```

before the profile argument on specific profile chrome shortcut.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not clear if the fix is to enable Windows 7 compatibility or the ordering of the arguments or if both are required.

Comment: Ok after I did some expirements only arguments order matter.